# getting right data types for values in a map

Tags: scala, dictionary, implicit

I have a

```
Map[String, Any]
```

The values in the map can be anything from Strings and Doubles to Sequences and Sequence of Maps. I want to make a function that recognizes the type of the value and returns it when the function is fed with a key.
The idea I have in mind is to make an implicit class that 'extends' the functionality of the `get` function in the scala `map` library and put it in my `package` file.
Something like this:

```
implicit class RichMap(map: Map[String, Any]) {
  def getImplicit(key: String) = {
    val value = map.get(key)
    value match {
      case None => throw NonExistentKeyException(key + "does not exist")
      case Some(v) => v match {
        case s: String => s
        //Other case statements
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
myMap.getImplicit(key)
```

As you can see, it is more of a 'Brute force'y approach. Is there a more generic/elegant approach I can use for my problem statement?

Comment: Just return `v`. If that's not what you're looking for, then your question is unclear.

Comment: In which way is that pattern match going to help? If your `Map` can contain `Any` type of value there is no way for the compiler to know beforehand which concrete type the get method has to return. When you have cases for `String`, `Int` and so on the return type of `getImplicit` will still be `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to return a type (class) of the element under `key`? In that case, how about

```
implicit class RichMap(map: Map[String, Any]) {
  def getImplicit(key: String) = map.get(key).map(_.getClass)
}
```

or if you really wish to throw an exception:

```
implicit class RichMap(map: Map[String, Any]) {
  def getImplicit(key: String) = {
    map.get(key) match {
      case None => throw NonExistentKeyException(key + "does not exist")
      case Some(v) => v.getClass
    }
  }
}
```